# QuerySelectorAll using a class and index number

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

```
document.querySelectorAll('.fixers > track > tnty')
```

On the DOM there are many classes named fixers is there a way to include what class number to use something like

```
document.querySelectorAll('.fixers[2] > track > tnty')
```

Currently I do this

```
document.getElementsByClassName('fixers')[2].querySelectorAll('track > tnty')
```

Is there a more correct way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-class to select the second group like so:

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.fixers:nth-child(2) > .track > .tnty');
console.log(elems);
console.log(elems[0].textContent);
```

```html
<div class="fixers">
  <div class="track">
    <div class="tnty">1</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="fixers"> <!-- 2 -->
  <div class="track">
    <div class="tnty">2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="fixers">
  <div class="track">
    <div class="tnty">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a selected ‘fixers’ element using a specific parent

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.special-parent .fixers > track > tnty')
```

or `:nth-child()` selector

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.fixers:nth-child(2) > track > tnty')
```

or using both above mentioned.